# How to use a variable to access a node by name

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How would you use a variable to specify an element? Specifically, I have the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="status" mode="status_summary">
  <div id="{@MSN}_{@IC}_{@ID}" class="hidden status_summary">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="group" mode="status_summary"/>
    <p>
    <button style="width:100%" onclick="showhide('{@MSN}_{@IC}_{@ID}')" >Hide</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I'd like to make this template more generic so that I can specify different attributes as necessary and perhaps also different quantities that are basically being used as unique keys.

e.g. instead of hardcoding `@MSN`, `@ID`, and `@IC`, I might want to use `@MSN` and `@USER` or any other combination.

Thanks.

Comment: "*How would you use a variable to specify an element?*" Actually, your example is about specifying an **attribute** - and if I understand correctly, it will be an attribute of the current element.

Comment: I changed the title, I went with "node" since I think you'd have the same type of problem whether it's an attribute node or element node.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an elegant way to do this in XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0), unless your processor supports some kind of an `evaluate()` function as an extension.

One possible method could be:

```
@*[name()=$variable]
```